# PHP/MySQL - Update array if variable does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array with different IDs which I get from my database.

```
$fotos_temp_list=explode(",",$fotos_temp["fa_id"][0]);
Result: fa_id => 15,16,17,18
```

Now I want to update all rows inside another table with the IDs 15,16,17,18 and insert a specific `'$id'` into a column called `'fa_ev_id'`.
In this example I set:

```
$id=1;
```

Now my foreach-loop looks like this:

```
foreach ($fotos_temp_list as $key) {
    UPDATE images SET fa_ev_id = Concat(fa_ev_id , ',' ,'".$id."') where fa_id='".$key."' ";
}
```

This part is working too.
Every row with my IDs (in my example: 15,16,17,18) gets updated.

**Problem:**
When I run the foreach-loop again, the `'$id'` will be saved again inside the row. See here:

[image]

**Question:**
How is it possible, that I can check if `'$id'` is already inside the row and if so, it gets skipped? Here is what I tried to do:

```
foreach ($fotos_temp_list as $key) {
    if (!in_array($id,$key)===true) {
        UPDATE fotoalbum SET fa_ev_id = Concat(fa_ev_id , ',' ,'".$id."') where fa_id='".$key."'
    }
}
```

I think the `in_array` function checks if `'$id'` id already inside `'$key'` and if it is true, the UPDATE statement is done. Therefore I added `'!in_array'` but it doesn´t seems to work. Does anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong? I just want to check if the `'$id'` is already inside my database row and if so, it should not insert the `'$id'` again.
I appreciate any advice.

Comment: What is type of field 'fa_ev_id' ?

Comment: Looks more like a problem of poorly structured database. Please explain to me, why are you saving IDs in a comma separated string instead of a typical [1-to-many model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model))?

Comment: what's in `$fotos_temp_list` at the time you run this? And why on earth are you storing multiple values inside a single field? A properly designed relational database would not do this. You should have one value per field. If you don't, it indicates a flaw in your schema design. Have you studied relational database design and normalisation at all?

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **in_array()** function in php accepts an array as its second parameter, in **(!in_array($id,$key)===true)**, https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp. The second parameter *$key*, passed in here isn't an array.

You could save the datatype of **fa_ev_id** as json, and retrieve and json_decode the value when you are about performing an update the field to know if that ***$id*** already exists using **in_array()** or you could retrieve the values, expolode them to form an array and then check if it exists with **in_array()**.

Comment: Thank you. I added your answer as the correct answer cause I ignored that $key cannot be an array. I fetched the data per json and checked with in_array() if the ID is already in. It works now. Thank you.

Comment: Please try to avoid linking to third-rate sites like w3schools. The official documentation is almost always far, far better, and includes community comments that improve it even more. Here's the [equivalent documentation for `in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).